# Upvoting Answers on Unanswered Questions

Tags: discussion, up-votes, unanswered-questions

Unanswered questions are Questions with no upvoted answers. Having recently looked at a sample of Unanswered questions, there seem to be a large proportion of poorly worded or vague questions, particularly when you get past the first few pages. Therefore, the answers that are given tend to be quite vague also.

My question is this: if an unanswered question has only *one* answer, then no matter how vague or general the response, is it acceptable to upvote it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The criteria seems pretty straight forward - you upvote the answer if you think it answers the question or adds critical information. If you can't determine that the answer deciphered the question correctly, don't grace it with an upvote "just for trying".

If the question is too vague the best you can do is leave a comment asking for a clarification of the question. If the asker doesn't come back there's not much you can do. Some questions are just destined to be unanswerable.

Comment: thanks for the advice - I just don't like the idea of having lots of unanswered questions hanging around, but accept that it sometimes can't be helped.